# Multiply 2 array index variables shell programming

Tags: shell, debugging, ubuntu, command-line

How do i multiply 2 array index variables given the following

```
foo=(1 2)
bar=(0.1 0.2)

foobar=$((foo[1]*price[1])) # this is wrong

echo "$foobar"
```

Current output : `0`

Correct/Expected output : `0.4`

Comment: I don't think you get non-integral numbers in bash.  What does `echo "$bar[1]"` get you?

Comment: sorry i just started on shell programming , very confused by syntax

Comment: I mean if you take out the echo line you have and put it the one I suggest, what do you get?  (I'm currently typing on a Win system where I can't get to bash at the moment, otherwise I'd check myself.)

Comment: also on http://askubuntu.com/q/403484/10127 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108733/4667

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash only does integer arithmetic. For floating point math, the usual course of action is to use [`bc`](http://man.cx/bc):

```
$ foobar=$(echo "${foo[1]} * ${bar[1]}" | bc)
$ echo $foobar
.4
```

Note the syntax required to de-reference an array element: the braces are required to group the variable name and the index together.

Comment: Thank for the help!!! What is the syntax required to dereference the array element??